# is the story of Siva being his own great grandfather in scripture?

Tags: shiva

The story goes that a saint asked Shiva who his grandfather was. Shiva replied that his grandfather was Vishnu, and his great-grandfather was himself

Is it scriptural or folklore?

Comment: According to Shiva Purana, Shiva is the Ever-existing Unborn Lord. From Shiva originates Vishnu, from the nabhipadma of Vishnu emerges Brahma & from Brahma's anger manifested Rudra, who is a tamasic reflection of Shiva. Many people, especially Vaishnavas take Rudra & Shiva to be the same entity, hence by combining Shaiva & Vaishnava narratives we get Shiva -> Vishnu -> Brahma -> Shiva lineage. The character of the questionnaire sage is perhaps fictional.